# How to interpret trackpad pinch gestures to zoom IKImageBrowserView

Tags: cocoa, macos, imagekit, ikimagebrowserview

I have an `IKImageBrowserView` that I want to be able to pinch-zoom using a multi-touch trackpad on a recent Mac laptop.

The Cocoa Event Handling Guide, in the section [*Handling Gesture Events*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html) says:

> *The magnification accessor method returns a floating-point (CGFloat) value representing a factor of magnification*

..and goes on to show code that adjusts the size of the view by multiplying height and width by `magnification + 1.0`.

This doesn't seem to be the right approach for zooming `IKImageBrowserView`, whose `zoomValue` property is clamped between 0.0 and 1.0.

So, does anyone know how to interpret the event in `-[NSResponder magnifyWithEvent:]` to zoom `IKImageBrowserView`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what I do, on Snow Leopard, it runs perfectly well:

In 10.6, `NSEvent` has the method "magnification" which will return the right amount already. All you have to do is add this to the old value, like `[imageBrowser zoomValue]+[event magnification]`.

```
- (void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
    if ([event magnification] > 0)
    {
        if ([self zoomValue] < 1)
        {
            [self setZoomValue:[self zoomValue] + [event magnification]];
        }
    }
    else if ([event magnification] < 0)
    {
        if ([self zoomValue] + [event magnification] > 0.45)
        {
            [self setZoomValue:[self zoomValue] + [event magnification]];
        }
        else
        {
            [self setZoomValue:0.45];
        }
    }
}
```

self here is a `IKImageBrowserView` subclass. I have a threshold here so that the `zoomValue` can not get smaller than 0.45, but that's just how I like it.

Best regards,
Matthias, Eternal Storms Software

Answer (score 5):

If you add the event magnification to your zoom factor, the same event will not have the same effect depending on the current zoom factor. Adding a magnification of `0.1` to a zoom factor of `1` will zoom by `10%`, but if the zoom factor is `0.1`, adding `0.1` will double your zoom.

The result of multiplying the zoom factor by `magnification + 1.0` will be more consistent.

I prefer multiplying the zoom factor by `std::exp(magnification)`, as it seems to be a more natural solution. A magnification of `-n` will zoom out exactly by the same amount that a magnification of `n` zooms in.